# coldfusion9 --- <cfprint> skips files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, cfdirectory, cfprint

ColdFusion 9 on Win2003.
I am building PDF files into a directory. I, then, loop over "spool" directory and trying to print all files in it. CF prints, but ... it skips over some files.
I read about similar problem here: [coldfusion - cfprint issues with large spool files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294383/coldfusion-cfprint-issues-with-large-spool-files) and trying to implement sleep() solution for printer to catch up. It does not work :-( as am still missing some files
Here is what I have:

```
<cfset spool_dir="D:\SPOOL\">    
<cfdirectory action="list" name="files" directory="#spool_dir#">
    <cfoutput query="files">
        <cfif files.currentRow MOD 5 EQ 0>
            Current document number: #files.currentRow# -- Sleeping, shhhhh ...<br>
            <cfset sleep(5000)>
        </cfif> 
        <cfprint type="pdf" source="#name#" printer="\\http://10.0.99.99\DC">
    </cfoutput>
```

Can anyone suggest  something else to try?

Comment: When it turns out something is a localized issue (i.e. problem specific to one environment only and the answer is unlikely to benefit others) you can always just delete the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that we had a faulty printer. I sent the same code to a different printer and it printed all documents.